# Unable to login using passport - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js

I am following one of the Udemy tutorial and I am stuck in the last bit of login process. I am able to register new user but unable to login. I enter email address and password. On pressing submit button regardless the value of email address or password being correct or wrong it triggers `failureRedirect` method of passport which pulls login page again, I have put several console.logs but none are printed in console. also if any random detail is enter it should throw  unknown user error. I am not sure what is causing it to not work, No error is seen or found in console or in the browser.

## form - login.ejs

```
<form class="form-signin" action="/login" method="POST">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
       <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

## routes - index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', { title: 'login', errors: false });
});


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function (email, password, done){ 
        console.log("testing... 1");
        User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user){
            if (err) throw err;
            if(!user){
                console.log('Unknown User');
                console.log("testing... 3");
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
            }

            User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
                console.log("testing... 2");
                if(err) throw err;
                if (isMatch){
                    return done(null, user);
                    console.log("testing... 4");
                }else{
                    console.log("Invalid Password");
                    return done(null,false, {message:'Invalid Password'});
                }
            });
        });
    }
));


router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'}), function(req, res) {

    console.log('Authentication successful');
    //Flash message
    req.flash('success','Your credentials match redirecting...');
    //Redirect to the dashboard page
    res.location('/dashboard');
    res.redirect ('/dashboard');

});
```

## model - user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db_name');
var db = mongoose.connection;

//User Schema

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String
    },
    password:{
        type:String, required:true, bcrypt:true
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, isMatch);

    });
}

module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
    var query = {email:email};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}
```

## mongodb - user collection object

```
db.users.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("594c330d520d491b18771425"),
        "name" : "John Doe",
        "email" : "john@gmail.com",
        "password" : "$2a$10$aFt9vfsSVJpFA8CMlCYIaOqQjW.6lV/1i0PibLelC43HscaAIvQPW",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
  done(err, user);
 });
});
```

If we serialize user object , then deserilaize user object not just the id

Please check the example here on https://github.com/rupalipemare/Mongoose-Demo, wherein there is complete example demonstrating passport authentication.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'}), function(req, res) {
```

Isn't it './login' ?

Comment: No, that's correct. I have all my routes without DOT. if I add DOT as u mentioned it throws not found error.